# EACCES : PM2 with command `npm run ...`

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I can't run PM2 with command `npm run ...` doesn't work.

`cross-env NODE_PATH=./src pm2-dev start ./src/server.js`

```js
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.pm2/logs'
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.pm2/pids'
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.pm2/module_conf.json'
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.pm2/modules'
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.pm2-dev/logs'
```

When I run directly `pm2-dev start ./src/server.js`, I have no problem.

I tried a lot of solutions found on the web, but anything not works.

- chmod 777 /usr/local
- reinstall npm and node
- remove and reintall PM2
- add `export PM2_HOME='/opt/.pm2'` on `etc/profile`

Env : Node 14.6, NPM 7.15, PM2 4.5.6, WSL Debian 10